Change the joins of a full outer join between 2 select queries using different facts
In OBIEE/OAC we sometimes observe that for a report, 2 select queries are generated, each using a different fact, in the session logs. Those 2 queries are then stitched using a full outer join and that outer join is created on key columns from both the queries. Something like this:
SAWITH1 AS (select F1.D1, F1.D2, F1.Ky1, F1.Ky2 from FACT1 F1),
SAWITH2 AS (select F2.D1, F2.D2, F2.Ky1, F2.Ky2 from FACT2 F2),

SAWITH3 AS (select T1.D1,T2.D2 FROM SAWITH1 T1 full outer join SAWITH2 T2 ON
T1.Ky1=T2.Ky1)

In this snippet D1, D2 are 2 dim columns and Ky1, Ky2 are two columns from each fact table FACT1 and FACT2. And the 2 queries are joined at FACT1.Ky1 and FACT2.Ky1 only. I want to know if there's a way to change the full outer join conditions in include another join condition, say FACT1.Ky1 and FACT2.Ky1, as well as FACT1.Ky2 and FACT2.Ky2, so the outer join statement will become something like this:
SAWITH3 AS (select T1.D1,T2.D2 FROM SAWITH1 T1 full outer join SAWITH2 T2 ON
T1.Ky1=T2.Ky1
and T1.Ky2=T2.Ky2)

Please let me know if more explanation is required in case I am not being very clear here.

Have you tried it? If the join conditions are that t1.ky1 = t2.ky1 and t1.ky2 = t2.ky2, then those are the join conditions. (The only issue I can see immediately is you have a . instead of a = in your second join condition)

Are you really doing reports as in "BI Publisher reports" or are you talking about analyses or are you talking about Workbooks?
Are you using an RPD Subject Area for this?

@Chris I am talking about Analysis. I am using FAW Semantic extension for creating the models, not the usual RPD. But even if we did used RPD, I'd be interested to know how we can implement.

FAW semantic extension does not allow you the full freedom of the Admin Tool or the Semantic Modeler but the dimensionality concepts are the exact same.
Cross-fact analysis happens over conformed and non-conformed dimensions surrounding the facts. You can navigate from one fact to the other over a shared  dimension but can still show non-conformed dimensions at the same time. The key is a correct and proper modelization of the content levels for the different dimension and fact sources.
